# Remove characters in ranges from a string

Tags: python, optimization

Curious to find if people can do much faster than my implementation (using pure python, or whatever, but then just for your sake).

```
sentence = "This is some example sentence where we remove parts"
matches = [(5, 10), (13, 18), (22, 27), (38, 42)]
```

The goal is to remove within those ranges. E.g. the characters at indices (5, 6, 7, 8, 9) should be ommited in the return value for match (5, 10).

My implementation:

```
def remove_matches(sentence, matches):
    new_s = ''
    lbound = 0
    for l, h in matches:
        news += sentence[lbound:l]
        lbound = h
    new_s += sentence[matches[-1][1]:]
    return new_s
```

Result: `'This me le sce where weove parts'`

Note that the matches will never overlap, you can make use of that fact.

Actually, my main question is simply: can we not do it somehow in some vectorized way? I'm sure that numpy could, but I doubt that would be more efficient in this case.

Benchmarks:

```
PascalvKooten:           1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 µs per loop
Ted Klein Bergman (1):   1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.59 µs per loop
Ted Klein Bergman (2):    100000 loops, best of 3: 2.58 µs per loop 
Prune:                    100000 loops, best of 3: 2.05 µs per loop
njzk2:                    100000 loops, best of 3: 3.19 µs per loop
```

Comment: If you give us your benchmarks, we might be able to test if we have something faster.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan: then it suffices to take his code and use a faster machine.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: By that logic, you may as well not profile at all.

Comment: I use IPython `%timeit`. I'll post my benchmarks.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan: What I mean is that timings made on different machines do not compare, so having those of PascalvKooten is of little use.

Comment: @YvesDaoust While that is true, it does help to have some sense of what 'faster' means. Good profiling reporting would ideally include some information about the machine itself.

Comment: @PascalvKooten If you can run `lscpu` (if on *nix) and/or post appropriate system information, that would help characterise your profiling as well.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan: it is much more useful to profile the reference implementation given by the OP on your machine.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you! I learned something new today :)

Comment: in `sentence[matches[-1][1]:]`, `matches[-1][1]` should be `lbound` (which also work in matches is empty)

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Best is to just run the benchmark for yourself. Take my code, and take your own code, and then you can do a comparison like that. You could also check other's to get a stable idea of how our PCs compare.

Answer (score 2):

This might be faster. It's basically your solution but with list instead of strings. Since lists are mutable and doesn't need to be created every loop, it should be faster by quite much (maybe not for such few matches though).

```
sentence = "This is some example sentence where we remove parts"
matches = [(5, 10), (13, 18), (22, 27), (38, 42)]

def remove_matches(sentence, matches):
    result = []
    i = 0
    for x, y in matches:
        result.append(sentence[i:x])
        i = y
    result.append(sentence[i:])

    return "".join(result)
```

This method might be quicker otherwise:

```
def remove_matches(sentence, matches):
    return "".join(
        [sentence[0:matches[i][0]] if i == 0 else 
         sentence[matches[i - 1][1]:matches[i][0]] if i != len(matches) else 
         sentence[matches[i - 1][1]::] for i in range(len(matches) + 1)
         ])
```

Comment: It's an interesting point about the lists. I can indeed see the effect as it scales up.

Answer (score 0):

```
shorthend =sentence[:matches[0][0]]+ "".join([sentence[matches[i-1][1]:matches[0][0] for i in range(1, len(matches)]) + sentence[matches[len(matches)]:]
```

Since I' on my phone right now, I cannot debug but it should work :D

Comment: I wrote that one as well. It's actually like 10% slower than my solution :D

Comment: Hmm, can't understand why. Probably creating the list just to turn it back into a string is the inefficient part there.

Comment: Yea, I think because it is relatively a small string.

Comment: Did you try it with lets say 10^4 characters and 10^2 ranges?

Comment: Actually, this code does not compile so I did not add it.

Answer (score 0):

If you append (null, 0) to the front and (-1, null) to the back of matches

```
sentence = "This is some example sentence where we remove parts"
matches = [(null, 0), 
           (5, 10), (13, 18), (22, 27), (38, 42), 
           (len(sentence), null)]
```

you can then write a join expression based on

```
matches[i][1]:matches[i+1][0] for i in range(len(matches)-1)
```

Is that enough of a hint to move you along?

Comment: It's a bit slower, though I doubt its significantly so. Note that (-1, ...) at the end will make us lose 1 character.

Comment: you can simply add `None` as `a[0:None]` is equivalent to `a[0:]`

Answer (score 0):

Had the strings be mutable, a fast solution would have been possible by moving the characters in-place, by contiguous substrings.

An optimal C solution would consist of a few memmov calls.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing characters, I would define how to keep them, to make the manipulation easier:

```
sentence = "This is some example sentence where we remove parts"
matches = [(5, 10), (13, 18), (22, 27), (38, 42)]
chain = (None,) + sum(matches, ()) + (None,)
# 
keep = ((m1, m2) for m1, m2 in zip(chain[::2], chain[1::2]))
# list(keep) = [(None, 5), (10, 13), (18, 22), (27, 38), (42, None)]
# or, keep = ((m1[1], m2[0]) for m1, m2 in zip([(None, None)] + matches, matches + [(None, None)]))
return ''.join(sentence[x:y] for x, y in keep)
```

Comment: It's quite slow for this small data, adding it to the benchmark results.